# AppCompat Fragment lifecycle changed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-appcompat, android-lifecycle, fragment-lifecycle

After updating to new appcompat library `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0` I've got new fragment lifecycle when replacing fragments in transaction.

E.g. I have two fragments `FrFirst` and `FrSecond` with logs in `onStart` and `onStop`, and I replace first with second and then second with first: `FrFirst -> FrSecond -> FrFirst`.

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.content, new FrSecond())
    .commit();
```

In previous appcompat version I can read this logs:

> FrFirst: Navigate to second
> FrFirst: stop
> FrSecond: start
>
> FrSecond: Navigate to first
> FrSecond: stop
> FrFirst: start

In 25.1.0 this logs:

> FrFirst: Navigate to second
> FrSecond: start
> FrFirst: stop
>
> FrSecond: Navigate to first
> FrFirst: start
> FrSecond: stop

So now `onStart` of presenting fragment called before then `onStop` of current.

Why method order changed, is it a bug in support library?

Comment: Check out - https://androidlearnersite.wordpress.com/2017/02/27/fragment-lifecycle-during-fragment-transaction/ ..It explains fragment lifecycle during fragmnet transaction with latest appcompat version

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is intended behaviour of new appcompat. 
As described here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=230415
this is a

> new functionality to optimize the operations and postpone fragment transitions and this is a side effect of that.
>
> You can disable fragment operation optimizations by calling FragmentTransaction.setAllowOptimization(false). This forces everything to happen in the proper order, but also disallows the operations from optimized.

So if you want to see old behaviour, you can replace fragments with disabled optimisation:

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.content, new FrSecond())
    .setAllowOptimization(false)
    .commit();
```

Comment: Thx! No idea why google didn't mention this fundamental fragment lifecycle change (!!!) in their support lib changelog..